# Do I need to set the Trailing/Leading constraint space to -20 in order for a UIElement to sit on the edge of the screen?

Tags: ios, autolayout

Is this the proper way to set constraints so my Map View will touch the edges of the screen?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of the `-20` like this

[image]

Uncheck the `Constrain to margins`:

[image]

If the constraint already exists, you can select the constraint and change its behavior afterwards as well:

[image]